# Bash: Get System-Information about a host on a different subnet

Tags: linux, bash, networking, hostname, mac-address

I´d like to ask if it is possible to get System-Information of a host on a different subnet such as MAC-Address or the hostname by using a bash script. 
I need those data to determine if a specific IP-Adress is taken, which host (MAC/Hostname) is using this IP-Address.
As I´ve seen, looking at the ARP-Table itself after pinging the host dosn´t work, because the MAC-Address is filtered by the routers if a remote device is pinging a host on a different subnet.

Thank you for your help,

Greetings

Comment: MAC addresses are only valid or seen on the LAN where the device is connected.

Comment: Hello and thank you, what is about the hostnames? Would it be possible to get the hostname of a device based on the IP-Address it has by a bash script?

Comment: If your systems are identified in DNS, and in the reverse lookup tables, yes you could.